# Control non-solution files with AnkhSVN

Tags: svn, version-control, ankhsvn

Our project has one folder that is not part of the solution.  How can I get AnkhSVN to recognise and manage this file together with the solution files?  I can' add it as a directory under the solution, as that structure is beyond my control.

Comment: Use the TortoiseSNV client from explorer?

Comment: That's what I do, and that's why I'm curious as to how to do it with Ankh.

Comment: Answered [Here][1]. I hope this solves your issue. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996332/ankhsvn-how-to-add-files-not-under-solution-to-svn-vs-2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many project types you can add files marked as 'content' or 'none' in the properties grid

These files won't be part of the build of your project, but these files are part of the solution and so they will be tracked by AnkhSVN.

For updating the workingcopy, AnkhSVN does a recursive update on the project roots in your workingcopies (Most likely the working copy root, unless you changed it in File->Subversion->Change Source Control).

It is just for committing/pending changes state that files should be part of your solution.