# AnkhSVN: How to add files not under Solution to SVN? (VS 2010)

Tags: visual-studio, svn, ankhsvn

just changed over form visualsvn to AnkhSVN. Loving it... but i need to add files and directory that are on my disk to SVN ... but the files and directory are not part the solutions (Vs2010) ... Its basically i directory where i store some dlls but if the directory is not present then i have missing references.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not from Ankh AFAIK. Get them in through Tortoise or the command line and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, yep still have tortoisesvn installed... will do that.. thanks again

Comment: Yes - though AnkhSVN supports Multiple "Working Sets" it can not be used to add non-svn items not under the solution directory. non solution-directory svn-items can be added as per @Sander's answer. for non-svn items You will have to add the external directory that contains these files externally using tortoisesvn. Now when you restart the IDE it should take it from there.

Answer (score 13):

You can either use "Show all files" in the solution explorer to reveal the files and add them, or use View -> Working Copy Explorer. Both solutions work in AnkhSVN.

Comment: hey thanks for the info! Although i didn't figure out once i do view, working copy explorer - how is it possible to add additional directories or files that are not in the solution??

Comment: Right-click and add? Or are they directories that aren't within a working copy, and you want to create a new working copy there?

Comment: Working Copy Explorer - can only be used to Explore and Add items already connected to svn. you cannot add **non svn** items using it.

Comment: @UjjwalSingh I have successfully added non svn items with this answer, so this is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

View Menu -> Working Copy Explorer -> navigate to your new file/directory -> right click and select "Subversion" -> then click "Add".